# How to make form submit to wait for validations to complete angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple form and i have to validate many input fields on ajax call.

Many of input fields are reusable so i have used directive for them.

```
<input name="UserName" 
       type="text" 
       user-name-unique 
       ng-model="UserName" 
       required 
/>
```

Directive function :

```
 elem.on('blur', function(evt) {
   scope.$apply(function() {
     var data = { 'username': elem.val() };
     var ajaxConfiguration = { method: 'POST', url: 'url', data: data };
     async(ajaxConfiguration).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       ctrl.$setValidity('userNameUnique', !data.IsSuccess);
     });
   });
 });
```

Similarly i have many directives which validates the input using ajax call.

How to make my submit function to wait for all my ajax requests to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a directive that your submit button can track, and then slap a `disabled` directive on your submit button that will only update once your custom directive fields are evaluated to true:

```
<input name="UserName" 
       type="text" 
       user-name-unique 
       ng-model="UserName" 
       required 
       validate="process()" //retun true/false, processed whenever value changes
/>


<form>
    <button type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then create a listener for when the input updates, and check it's validated state